# Can anyone tell me how $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2} = \frac{\pi + i\pi}{2\sqrt i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I was working out a problem last night and got the result

$\frac{\pi + i\pi}{2\sqrt i}$

However, WolframAlpha gave the result

$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}$

Upon closer inspection I found out that

$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2} = \frac{\pi + i\pi}{2\sqrt i}$

But I cant seem to derive it myself and it has been bugging me all day. How can this complex number be reduced to a real number?

Comment: The $\pi$ is not relevant. What you really ask is, why is: $\sqrt{i} = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$. Square the expression and use $i^2=-1$ to see why!

Comment: $\sqrt{i}$ is not a well-defined quantity.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**  $$(1+i)^2 = 2i{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: Such skillful character limit avoiding. +1 Also, its a pretty darn good answer, even though its short.

Comment: You can pad the character length by inserting `{}{}{}` into one of your formulas.

Comment: The square of both sides might be equal, but that doesn't necessarily mean the two sides are equal. Don't you agree?

Comment: Perhaps that's why the answer is labeled "hint".

Comment: @MJD: thanks!${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: if only the downvoters had to justify their vote here...

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting everything in polar form, the numerator is $\sqrt{2} \pi e^{i \pi/4}$ and the denominator is, for the choice of branch of $\sqrt{}$ that Wolfram is using, $2 e^{i \pi/4}$. So the $e^{i \pi/4}$ terms cancel and you're left with a real number.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:
Let $z=a+bi$ where $a,b$ belong to the set of all real number.

We would like to solve for $a$ and $b$ such that $z^2=i$, that is $(a+bi)^2=0+i$

Then, you will know why $\sqrt{i}= \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ and how to solve your problem.